# How to assign figure property with movegui() on Matlab subplot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

I need to assign the units *inches* for subplots (1-2). 
I added *movegui()* for the figure, after which I started to get the error. 
Without it, I donot get the error message. 
Code

```
hFig3=figure('Units', 'inches', 'Name', 'Time, Potential, T-p, T-p tiff');
movegui(hFig3,'northeast'); % without this, you do not get the error
% TechnicalMonitoring
b1=subplot(2,2,1); 
b2=subplot(2,2,2); 
b3=subplot(2,2,3); 
b4=subplot(2,2,4); 

% b1, b2 
hFig3.Children(1).Units = 'inches';
hFig3.Children(2).Units = 'inches';
```

Error

```
No public property Units exists for class matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder.

Error in code_1s (line 488)
    hFig3.Children(1).Units = 'inches';
```

Matlab: 2016a
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error, but if you want to assign the units for specific subplots, then assign it explicitly for them rather than relying on `hFig3.Children` to return the subplots in a particular order. You can do this by passing an array of `axes` to `set`.

```
set([b1 b2], 'Units', 'inches')
```

Or if you really want to use dot notation you can do them individually

```
b1.Units = 'inches';
b2.Units = 'inches';
```

Or you can just set this when they are created

```
subplot(2, 2, 1, 'Units', 'Inches');
```

Comment: I really love your first proposal with array, which I have missed so much, and I should be able to learn to use it because my code looks really crappy without it; because I have many figures and have much complications of interacting figures/subplots/...

Comment: @Masi Whenever possible, try to alter graphics objects explicitly rather than assuming that they are stored somewhere or that they are the current object. This way you get a GUI that will work no matter what!

Comment: Can you do similarly for a figure object like `set([hFig], 'Position', unitsPerInches(:,index);`. Currently, I have `hFig.Position = unitsPerInches(:,index);`, but actually, I have also other figures which need the same `unitsPerInches` so maybe possible `set([hFig, hFig2], 'Position', unitsPerInches(:,index);`. - - What do you think?